# Accessing JSON by key and index

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to access a JSON object by key AND index? I am running into the problem where I  need to be getting by key, and setting by index.

Comment: any code examples that would better to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properites of an object in JSON are considered unordered, so it makes no sense to access them via an index.

You could consider duplicating the data in the JSON once in an object, once in an array, that is how ever usually a bad idea, since the point of JSOn usally is to be consise.

Better would be to have the application using the data, preprocess it and "convert" the object into an array (or vice versa).

For a more detailed answer you will need to provide a pertinent example.

Comment: This is enough for me, as of now, my data is already duplicated 3 times (in the view, in the querystring, and in the object). At that point, I'm better off switching to a JS framework (backbone/angular etc). I got to work around my issue by accessing the key that was used in my view. Thank you.