# get json key and value by index instead of their names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's my Json

`var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');`

I can get the values of the json by using it's key like `console.log(obj.name);`

But I want to get the values by index instead of a key something like `console.log(obj[0]);`

[this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23321997/11333553) here said it's not good because the JSON are unordered but In my case the order will always be same no matter what.

```
$.each(obj ,function(i,item){
    console.log(i+' '+item);
});
```

The above code will return the keys and values all at once but I want to show it one by one.

If I can get the values by index it will be very helpful for me to show the data to user.

So is it possible ??

Comment: If you want an indexed collection, use an array

Comment: @SaurabhYadav then how to convert a json to array??

Comment: You can convert your json into array using `Object.entries`.

Comment: "this guy" is right! I don't know how you can be sure that the order will always be the same, except if you order the keys when you use indexes, like through `Object.keys(obj).sort()`.

Comment: @vicraj because I will send it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the values into an array with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then get the index you want:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}')
console.log(obj.name) // John
var array = Object.values(obj)
console.log(array[0]) // John
```

Comment: just what I needed.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v], i) => console.log(i, k, v))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` method or `Object.values` or you can use `Map` which holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys

> The [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original
>   insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive
>   values) may be used as either a key or a value.

`Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own
 enumerable property values

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');


for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}



const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj));

for (var [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}


let values = Object.values(obj);
console.log(values);
```